# What is the highest number of forced checkmates in a legal position?

Tags: problems, records, forced-move

Having been inspired by a [similar question,](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/24033/a-position-in-which-checkmate-is-forced-obligatory/24034#24034) what legal positions have the most forced checkmates for one side and for both sides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this has already been given as an [answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/24033/a-position-in-which-checkmate-is-forced-obligatory/24076#24076) in a related question. That answer was 55.

```
[Title "Ludwig Zagler, Feenschach 1972"]
[FEN "1rB1Q1Q1/1PRQ3Q/2b2k2/2pQ1N1Q/4KRPp/5N2/1R6/B3nn1b w - - 0 1"]
```

The position is taken from [Tim Krabbe's website](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/diary_17.htm). According to Krabbe:

> There are 12 mates by Rb2; 1 by g5; 1 by Qd5; 7 by d7; 7 by Qe8, 7 by
>   Qg8; 6 by Qh5; 6 by Qh7; and 8 by Nf5, for a total of 55.

The record with both sides to move is 39 according to [this Matplus.net thread](http://matplus.net/start.php?px=1586184928&app=forum&act=posts&tid=607&fid=gen&page=2).

```
[Title "Ludwig Zagler, Fairy Chess 6/1974"]
[FEN "6B1/2p2R1B/2P1k1NR/2P1q1PP/1pp1Q1p1/brn1K1p1/1b1r2P1/n1b5 w - - 0 1"]
```